# SQL XML to Unicode no encoding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xml

I want to export a varchar(max) column (SQL 2005) to an xml UTF 8 using BCP out to a file. 
I tryed using the -w option for BCP but so far it encodes my special characters in strings like –

Is there's an option to skip the special characters because I don't want any & or # in my final xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML encodes special characters using the escape sequences. When you ask for XML not to contain escape sequences for special characters you ask for XML which is not XML, so its an inherent contradiction. You can ask for a string or you can ask for an XML. Make up your mind.

Comment: You're right Remus !